# TlistView OnItemClick selects first record on iOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe8

I'm writing an app for multi platforms - (iOS, Android, Windows) The main form contains a `TListView` which fetches database records via dataset - `TFDMemTable`.

Using the **OnItemClick procedure** for the `TListView` I am using a `ShowMessage` dialog box to display the record's text, just to indicate that what I'm pressing is the correct record.

This appears to work fine for Android and Windows however when I press a record on the `ListView` on iOS platform, the ShowMessage dialog box always displays the text of the very first record no matter which record I press.

This is all I'm doing when pressing the record:

```
procedure TForm.ListViewItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  ShowMessage(DMod.InvTB.FieldByName('InvID').asString);
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't should you be using the `AItem` that is the Item that you pressed to find your record before display the message?

Comment: Yep you're right, I didn't spot it at first. All sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AItem.tag to a relevant integer fieldname to identify the record.